# Push messages to android using PHP without GCM or FCM

Tags: php, android, sockets, socket.io

I need some methods for pushing JSON messages to android application from the server using PHP but without GCM or FCM.

I don't want to use Google because it sometimes doesn't send messages or they arrive in late, and I need a reliable service.

My goal is to update some text views when something happens on the server, for example, a user subscribes for a live game, so other users see the number of players increased real-time.

Also, I'm a little ashamed, I'm not able to use other server languages except PHP, and even if I could, my hosting service is not able to install Node or other languages. Moreover, my hosting server doesn't support the composer, so I need to install libraries manually.

I try to use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), and it works fine, but it costs too much if one day I reach a good number of players. Actually, my budget is 0 :(
I also heard about [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) but I don't know how to use it with PHP. If someone uses it with PHP I'm really happy to see a front-end and back-end simple examples.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Try using sockets

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Yes, I thought about this solution, but I didn't understand how it works, can you post a very simple example? Thank you

Comment: @Kushan How it works? It's different from FCM? I don't need a database, because I use a mysql db

Comment: affordable? FCM is free\

Comment: @PembaTamang ups! I accepted an edit from a user, and I didn't see that error, I would like to say "reliable" :)

Comment: fcm is pretty reliable..what is your problem with the service?

Comment: @PembaTamang well, fcm is built for push notifications, so it uses a service. That service always stops and messages don't arrive or arrive in late. I need messages for update my ui, so it's important that messages always arrive. I don't want to use it for notifications, only for real time updates

Comment: realtime updates are hard to maintain since oreo I think.
Plenty of restrictions

Comment: @PembaTamang sure using fcm it's hard, but other services like Pusher work fine, so I think it is possible. But those services cost, unfortunately

Comment: pusher works all the time??

Comment: @PembaTamang Yes, as I remember. I used it last year (2018) and it worked. Then I stopped to use it because of its price

Answer (score 0):

Your use case would be best served with something like Firebase Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore or if you want your own server stack, something like Parse.

Doing this will avoid the use of server side code. Also you can react to real time changes with all of the above. All these intrinsically do run over Sockets so instead of rolling out your own, i suggest you have a look at these and try to fit these for your use case.

Using notifications for this is kind of an overkill and may cause your app to get blacklisted for overly spamming users.

Comment: I need to use a mysql database so I cannot ignore server side. But can you post a little example? I'm interested to Parse, what it is?

Comment: similar to firebase but made by facebook. I m not saying ignore server side, i am saying your use case using firebase wont need server side code for the reacting to user count part. Don't have any particular examples but you can google them, they're pretty popular and will have a lot of examples

Comment: Thank you! I'm taking a look and trying those... I hope well :)

Comment: mark as accepted so people dont waste time trying to answer an already answered question :)

Comment: Yes, I will do it, if them will works fine ;) I think it's better to have many opinions, right?